# Нужна ли запятая на месте пропуска?

Tags: запятые, деепричастный-оборот, деепричастия, придаточное-предложение

***"Она ходила по комнате, не зная (?) куда себя деть".***

Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• Я думаю, что нужна.
Придаточное предложение отделяется запятой, ставится она и после деепричастия (перед "куда").

Заглянем в словарь русского языка под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой:
[*не знать, **куда** деть себя*](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C) — не знать, чем заняться, что делать.

Посмотрим во фразеологическом словаре русского литературного языка:
[*не знать, **куда** себя девать (деть)*](https://phraseology.academic.ru/3177/%D0%9D%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%2C_%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%28%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%29) — экспрес., не знать, чем заняться от расстройства, скуки, апатии. *Сегодня сидел у меня Бунин с растрёпанными нервами, не знает, куда себя деть* (Чехов. Письмо О. Л. Книппер, 21 дек. 1900 г.).

• Примеры из Нацкорпуса

*Люся не смотрела и не видела, как густо, **не зная, куда себя девать,** залилась краской Надя* (Валентин Распутин. Последний срок).

***Не зная, куда себя деть** и как держаться, Лена подошла к той койке, на которой лежал Панасюк...* (Юрий Герман. Дорогой мой человек).

*Феня томилась, **не зная, куда себя девать*** (В. П. Катаев. Время, вперед!).

• Дополнительная информация

> **4.** Между главной и следующей за ней придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения запятая не ставится: <...>
> **3)** если придаточная часть состоит из одного союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия): <...>  *Трудно сказать **почему**; Он ушёл и не сказал **куда**; Он обещал скоро вернуться, но не уточнил **когда***...

[Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137) (Розенталь)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос **неоднозначный,** вполне можно допустить **отсутствие** запятой перед "куда":

*Она ходила по комнате, не зная  **куда себя деть**.*

Поэтому я не стала сразу отвечать, чтобы услышать другие **мнения**. Как и ожидалось, запятая была **поставлена**...

**Пояснение**

1. Вот интересный вариант:

**[Леха Ан](https://stihi.ru/2006/12/14-1766)**

***Не знаю куда себя дЕть…** Очень суетливо, не постоянно внутри… Мысли как тараканы разбегаются по всему мозгу. Безумное количество импульсов. Медленно схожу с сума…*

У этого автора ударение явно уходит на конец предложения, паузы после ***не знаю*** нет (в предложении **одно** ударение!).

2. Это тема **["Цельные по смыслу выражения"](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146),** где очень многое зависит от **структуры и интонации**. С другой стороны, речь идет не только о цельных выражениях, так как приходится учитывать **фразеологичность** (образное значение) речевого оборота.
3. Есть еще вариант **без запятой**, как я думаю:

*Она ходила по комнате,  не зная  **куда девАться**.*

Или так:  *Вещей — **не знаешь куда деть!***

4. **Синоним**: *Весь следующий день он ходил **не находя себе места,** с трудом подавляя желание снова повидать Мечика.* Обособления нет.

**ВЫВОД**

Здесь видно явное **противоречие** между **грамматической** структурой (постановка запятой рекомендуется), и **фразеологическим** характером оборота, который при обособлении приобретает **нежелательное** прямое значение.

Comment: Sharon, вы видели комментарий, который я здесь написал?

Comment: Не видела. И где же ваш комментарий?

Comment: Да он не слишком важен, поэтому и удалил. Писал о том, что ваш ответ мне тоже нравится, он понятен и заставляет задуматься. Только вот Леха Ан очень уж "ненадёжный" автор: "Медленно схожу **с сума**", "...был **более менее** счастлив и **не какого** напряжения, **ни каких** посторонних мыслей", ну и далее в том же духе.

Comment: Ваш голос? Спасибо,  вы часто голосуете за альтернативные ответы, я заметила.  // Я в смысл и грамотность Лехи Ан  особо не вчитывалась.  Но в данном тексте эту фразу невозможно прочитать с обособлением. А потом мне и вообще расхотелось обособлять оборот в любых случаях.

Comment: Угу, ага, класс!